# Matching numbers and colors

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm sorry I can't ask this problem in a more formal way, the issue being that I'm not even sure what type of math this involves; I *think* it actually translate to a graph-coloring problem?

FWIW, it's about figuring how many races I need so I can distribute them among guilds/factions for a game.

- I have the number 1-10, separated between even and odd numbers.
- Each number needs to have at least three colors.
- No more than two odd or two even numbers can share a given color, but colors can be shared otherwise between odd and even numbers.
- Each number has a unique set of colors.
- This include not sharing all colors with a number that can be a greater number of colors.

Given these parameters, how many colors am I going to need? Does that minimum changes if I allow...

1. For a number that can only be 2 color?
2. For a color that can be shared by 4 numbers?
3. for both of the above?

Comment: From your description, you could use zero colors.  I'm guessing that every number has to have at least one color.  Are there an equal number of even and odd numbers? Can we just assume that the numbers are 1,2,3,...,10? It seems to me that there is no benefit to giving a number more than one color: all that would do is make it share more colors with other numbers.  Can an odd and an even number share a color? So, could 1,2 and 3 all be the same color?

Comment: @MatthewConroy Thanks for asking obvious questions. I realise I'd also forgotten to mention the color combinations need to be unique. As mentioned briefly, the idea is that I need to create a set of 10 guilds (numbers) with unique combinations of possible races (colors), with extra factors (hence the even/odd thing). I'm trying to figure out how many races I'm gonna have to work with or I have to give myself more flexibility, but I can't figure it out because I've stopped at high-school maths and that's way back already.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the update.  To make sure I understand your fifth bullet point, you mean that the set of colors for a number cannot be a subset of any other set of colors, right? So if one number had colors {a,b,c}, then another could not have {a,b,c,d}, yes?

Comment: @MatthewConroy Yes. Wish I'd known the proper formal way to explain it, but I have to work with what knowledge I do have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, each color can appear at most 4 times: on two odd teams, and two even teams. Since there are at least 30 slots to fill, we certainly need at least $30/4=7.5$ colors. Indeed, 8 will suffice.

Say the colors are ABCDEFGH. One (uninspired) arrangement satisfying the requirements is:

1. ABC
2. ABD
3. ABE
4. ABF
5. FGH
6. EGH
7. DGH
8. CGH
9. CDE
10. DEF

Perhaps you can arrange them in a more varied manner.

If the teams only require two colors each, then five colors suffice:

1. AB
2. AC
3. AE
4. AD
5. BC
6. BD
7. CD
8. BE
9. DE
10. CE

Comment: Thanks. It's a good baseline for what I need.